# rake db:rollback not working? After missing dbmigrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran 'scaffold' and 'migrate'

And then I regret, and run `rails d scaffold xxx` then `db:rollback`

And found the scheme.rb didn't change.

I though it's because that the `migrate file` is missing. How to recover it ?

`% rake db:migrate:status`

```
   up     20140916064606  Create tool mvaas securities
   up     20140918034311  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20140918035954  Create tool cvt remote focus
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

### 1. Use Git

If your work is under version control and you've previously committed the missing migration, `git checkout` to before you deleted the migration, copy the migration content, `git checkout` again back to the present, paste the copied migration content into a new migration with the same timestamp as the old one. Now `db:rollback` should work.

### 2. Scaffold again

If your lost migration never made it to version control, but you remember the fields defined in the scaffold (have a look at `schema.rb`, if the rollback failed all the fields should still be there) then you can re-scaffold, modify the newly created migration file name to have the same timestamp as the old one, and `db:rollback`. Then 'rails d scaffold' to clean things up.

### Future code

I suspect you've already learned this the hard way, but in future it'll serve you well to `db:rollback` first, and `rails d scaffold` next.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for 2nd option. But No need to run scaffold for this. Just need to create a migration put feilds from `schema.rb`. Rename migration version to `20140918034311` And rollback is sufficient enough.